# Вхождения числа в множество

Tags: php

Как записать такое условие вхождения числа в множество чисел на php:

```
IF (Число IN (Число1, Число2, Число3)) THEN
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$n = 5;

if(in_array($n, array(2, 4, 8)))
{
    echo $n, ' in array';
}
else
{
    echo $n, ' not in array';
}
```